# RegEx for enclosed date interval

Tags: php, regex, date

I am having trouble generating a regular expression in PHP for the following pattern:

```
(dd/mm/yyyy - dd/mm/yyyy)
```

where:

- `dd` - day index (1-31)
- `mm` - month index (1-12)
- `yyyy` - year

For example, `(12/12/2018 - 11/01/2019)` should pass the `preg_match`.

Comment: You could go crazy and use subroutines: https://regex101.com/r/6bFwWs/1 - better yet, use `strtotime`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code:

```
<?php 
$subject = "12/2/1987 - 11/5/2012";
if(preg_match_all("/(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}) - (\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})/",$subject, $matches))  {
        echo "Matched Date";

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

use regrex = '/^(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}\s-\s\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4})$/m';

you can use above regrex in order to match the date in code.
[Live Demo with Code in all languages](https://regex101.com/r/6CJZOH/1)